# how to traverse two php variables and aggregate them in a sql condition

Tags: php, mysql

hello to all I am trying to make the impression of some values through a query where I would like to take into account the variables t1 and t2 in the where but I do not know how to add them or correctly perform the while cycle

```
<?php

$t1='xxx';
$t2='yyy';
$c=1;
$d='t';

while($c<=2){
$sql = "select type from table where type='$d.$c'";
 $res = mysqli_query($bd, $sql);
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
 echo $row['type'];
}
$c=$c+1;
}
return $c;
?>
```

Comment: If the vars are just to be strung together, then `"…type='$d$c'"` possibly.

Comment: is that I would like to place in the where type = '$ t1' and get the data for that condition, but somehow return in the same cycle and also get the values if I put where type = '$ t2'

Comment: Show some database samples, and explain what you want to select. → [edit]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `REGEX` to match both the 1 and 2 like:

```
SELECT type
FROM table
WHERE type REGEXP 't\.[12]`
```

SQL statements in a loop is usually an indication that you are doing something incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question. have you tried adding them in the variable before passing it in a query something like

```
$dc = $d.$c;
```

The code becomes

```
<?php

$t1='xxx';
$t2='yyy';
$c=1;
$d='t';
$dc = $d.$c;

while($c<=2){
$sql = "select type from table where type='$dc'";
 $res = mysqli_query($bd, $sql);
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
 echo $row['type'];
}
$c=$c+1;
}
return $c;
?>
```